# Clearing cache in weblogic server 10.3 during server runtime

Tags: caching, weblogic

Does anybody know how to clear cache from Weblogic server while it is running.Is there any way to access JMX console to access cache module to clear?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which cache are you referring to?

Answer (score 10):

Don't clear the cache when your server is running, in order to clear the cache in a Weblogic server you should:

1. Shut down your Server.
2. Delete the contents in the folder `ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/your_domain/servers/your_server/tmp`
3. Start your server.

Also if your server is connected to an IDE you can right click your server and you can clear the cache from there as well(the server should be shut down).

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can create two clusters and clear the cache of each one after turning them off sequentially.